# localstack + docker-compose + S3

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

I got a service in Java with Spring-boot + spring-cloud-aws-messaging ... that uploads files into S3 ...

It's failing when tries to upload a file into S3 bucket (only when I run it in docker-compose).

here is my code

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

S3 client

```
 public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(appConfig.getAwsS3Endpoint(), appConfig.getRegion()))
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
```

docker-compose yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  dumb-service:
    build: ../dumb-service/.
    image: dumb-service:latest
    hostname: dumb-service
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '5006:5006'
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5006' 
      AWS_S3_ENDPOINT: 'http://localstack:4566/'
      AWS_S3_BUCKET: 'dumb-bucket'
      AWS_SQS_ENDPOINT: 'http://localstack:4566'
      PDF_REQUEST_QUEUE_URL: 'http://localstack:4566/000000000000/dumb-inbound.fifo'
      PDF_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME: 'dumb-inbound.fifo'
      AWS_REGION: "${AWS_REGION}"
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
    depends_on:
      - "localstack"

  # localstack home: https://github.com/localstack/localstack
  localstack:
    hostname: localstack
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
      - '4571:4571'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=${SERVICES-}
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}localstack
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Error is:

**Unable to execute HTTP request: dumb-bucket.localstack**

(This code is working fine with AWS services or running code native + localstack)

Any thoughts about how to connect to localstack S3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access an s3 bucket with localstack via an aws api; you would need to `withPathStyleEnabled` flag turned on.

for eg:

```
    AmazonS3 createLocalStackS3WithEndpointConfig(String endpointUrl, String awsRegion) {
    return createAwsBeanWithEndpointConfig(
        endpointUrl, awsRegion,
        epConf -> AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(epConf).withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true).build(), 
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder::defaultClient
    );
} `
```

Reference : Troubleshooting section of https://pythonrepo.com/repo/localstack-localstack

Comment: solved ! Thank you !